# How to change style to every other line using loops in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a program where a list is generated upon user's initialization of list items.

Now I want to modify my loop so that every other line's text is colored, for example red AND blue, i.e. line 2 is red, line 4 is blue, 6 red, 8 blue and so on.

I'm not sure how I should write the loop?

Code:

```
<div id="list"><div>
...

        var entries = Number(prompt("How many list items would you like?"));
        list = document.getElementById("list");
        var temp = "<ol>";
        for (i = 1; i <= entries; i++){
            temp += "<li>";
            temp += "List item " + i;
            temp += "</li>";
        }
        temp += "</ol>";
        list.innerHTML = temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS for the effect that you want.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

But if you still want to use JavaScript, you can keep your current for loop but use a check within the loop to see if you're on an odd or even index.

```
if (i % 2 == 0) {
    if (i % 4 == 0) {
        element.style.color = 'blue';
    } else {
        element.style.color = 'red';
    }
}
```

I'm also not sure if you realize, but you need to be using `document.createElement` to actually create the DOM elements you want. That `element.style` wouldn't work unless `element` were an HTML DOM element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

If instead you still want to use `innerHTML`, I suppose you can do this within the loop (just using a ternary conditional to show another way of writing the if-else):

```
temp += "<li style='background: ";
if (i % 2 == 0) {
    temp += (i % 4 == 0) ? "blue" : "red";
}
temp += "'>";
temp += "List item " + i;
temp += "</li>";
```

Comment: Should I use this if inside the for loop before </li>?

Comment: You can do it after you've created the element in the loop. The element needs to have been created in order to set its style.

Comment: I noticed you said you wanted to alternate colors "every other line", which would mean 1 is red, 2 is blue, 3 is red, 4 is blue, etc. That's what my answer was assuming. But then your example says 2 is red, 4 is blue, 6 is red, 8 is blue. That would be every other even line. Which pattern were you intending?

Comment: You're right, I didn't specify my requirements clearly. I do mean the latter, i.e. line 1 default, 2 red, 3 default, 4 blue, 5 default, etc.

Comment: In that case, I've updated my answer to do the latter. The modulo `%` operator checks for remainder, so `i % 2 == 0` checks if it's divisible by 2 or whatever divisor you choose.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the modulo operator

```
if (i % 2 == 0) {
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
if (i % 2 == 0) {
   if (i % 4 == 0) {
      // change color blue
   } else {
      // change color red
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS solution -

```
 li { color: green; }
 li:nth-child(odd) { color: red; }
 li:nth-child(even) { color: blue; }
```